# Are non-English questions allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Are non-English questions allowed on SQA? I have not seen anything in the help pages or the tour for SQA. I know that Stack Overflow treats non-English as off topic with a reason of [unclear what you are asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content). Does the same apply here on SQA?

I ask because of [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/37376/c-erro-no-loop-for-com-if-em-uma-pesquisa-de-string).

Comment: Related: [Non-English Question Policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) and [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) (applies to all sites with exception of localized SE sites and foreign languages)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT.  I think your comment might be written as an answer, together with the general rule that non-English questions can be closed as "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @AndrewT Adrian is absolutely correct, you should make an answer. That is exactly what I would have linked to and summarized in my answer. :-)

Comment: @AdrianHHH Note that the edited question is good *now*, and the non-English variable names are acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, posts on SE has to be in English (with exception on some SE sites).

As long as it's in salvageable English, feel free to edit and improve it. However, avoid translating the post by yourself because:

1. you might accidentally change the intent, and
2. for OP who has a difficulty in English, there's a possibility that the English posts won't be helpful to them.

When you encounter non-English questions, flag/vote to close as "unclear". For non-English answer, flag as "very low quality". Also, consider commenting on the post to let OP know that the post has to be in English, and ask them to translate it to English.

For non-English code, it's allowed as long as the code is understood. Otherwise, feel free to ask for clarification like the meaning of the variable/constant/function.

---

Further reading: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), [How to treat English questions which have code in a foreign language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194059/how-to-treat-english-questions-which-have-code-in-a-foreign-language/194062#194062)